# WebGL Texture resize unexpected output

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, textures, webgl, texture-mapping

When using textures in WebGL, sometimes I need to make them larger than they were originally.  When I do that, it causes the textures to appear differently, especially on lighter backgrounds.

I have the following image (256 x 256):

[image: original image]

When rendered in WebGL, it is slightly larger than the original image.  Here is how the image appears on two different backgrounds:

[image] [image: image on light background]

As you can see, the image appears correctly on the dark background, but when on the light background, has a white outline.

My setup code:

```
gl.clearColor(0x22 / 0xFF, 0x22 / 0xFF, 0x22 / 0xFF, 1); // set background color
gl.enable(gl.BLEND); // enable transparency
gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST); // disable depth test (causes problems with alpha if enabled)
gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); //set up blending
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //clear the gl canvas
gl.viewport(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //set the viewport
```

And this is the code called every time a texture is loaded:

```
function handleTextureLoaded(image, texture) {
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
  loadCount++;
}
```

What is causing the outline to appear, and how do I fix it?

**NOTE:** When I put the original image on these same two backgrounds, this problem does not occur, even when I resize the image.

I tried disabling the alpha on the WebGL context (as told by @zfedoran):

```
gl = canvas.getContext('webgl', {antialias: false, alpha: false }) 
  || canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl', {antialias: false, alpha: false });
```

And a small blank border now appears around the image, like this (enlarged):

[image]

Comment: [Here's some experiments](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/zwLbz7xq/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried disabling the alpha on the WebGL context?

```
var gl = this.canvas.getContext('webgl', {antialias: false, alpha: false }) 
      || this.canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl', {antialias: false, alpha: false });
```

Comment: This made everything appear much better, but now there is a very thin, almost unnoticeable, black border.  I posted what it looks like in my question.  Also, Could you explain what disabling the alpha on the context does? Because I can still make things transparent.  Thank you.

Comment: The `alpha:true` makes the canvas opaque to the DOM elements underneath. If this is not something you want, try setting the document body color (with CSS) to the same color as your WebGL reset color. The black border may be due to how anti-aliasing is handled.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this.  I will play around with it to try and fix the black border.

Answer (score 5):

On top of the canvas's alpha as mentioned by @zfedoran how do you make the original image?

I believe the issue is as follows

Let's say you have an anti-aliased edge like this. What color is this pixel?

[image]

Assume the main color, the color of the pixels in the bottom right, was 1,0,0 (pure red).  Ideally the pixel pointed to by the arrow would be (1,0,0,0.5). In other words, pure red with an alpha of 0.5. But, depending how on the image was created to generate that anti-aliased pixel it might have been blended with the purely transparent pixels next to it so it no longer pure red. Those purely transparent pixels are likely (0,0,0,0) which is transparent **black**.

Even if your drawing program handles this correctly, GL likely does not. When you draw an image with texture filtering on (`gl.LINEAR` etc) GL is going to average the pixels near each other, some of those pixels are transparent **black**. Blending black with red gives dark red. Hence you get a dark border.

[Here you can see the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/vtub4wg7/)

```js
"use strict";

function main() {
  var planeVertices = [
       -1, -1,
        1, -1,
       -1,  1,
        1,  1,
    ];
      
  var texcoords = [
     0, 1,
     1, 1,
     0, 0,
     1, 0,
  ];
    
  var indices = [
     0, 1, 2,
     2, 1, 3,
  ];
    

  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {alpha:false});

  var programs = {}
  programs.normalProgram = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(
      gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"], ["a_position", "a_texcoord"]);
  programs.preMultiplyAlphaProgram = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(
      gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "pre-2d-fragment-shader"], ["a_position", "a_texcoord"]);
    
  var positionLoc = 0;  // assigned in createProgramsFromScripts
  var texcoordLoc = 1;  // assigned in createProgramsFromScripts

  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array(planeVertices),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Float32Array(texcoords),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(texcoordLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(texcoordLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    
  var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
      new Uint16Array(indices),
      gl.STATIC_DRAW);    

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = createTextures;
  img.src = document.getElementById("i").text;
    
  function createTexture() {
    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
    gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D); // assuming power-of-2 
    return tex;
  }
 
  var textures = {};    
  function createTextures() {
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, false);
    textures.unpremultipliedAlphaTexture = createTexture();
    gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
    textures.premultipliedAlphaTexture = createTexture();
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
    insert("original image");
    document.body.appendChild(img);
    render();
  }
    
  function insert(text) {
    var pre = document.createElement("pre");
    pre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    document.body.appendChild(pre);
  };
    
  function grabImage(prg, blend, texName) {
     document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("hr"));
     insert(
       "gl.useProgram(" + prg + ")\n" +
       "gl.blendFunc(gl." + blend.src + ", gl." + blend.dst + ")\n" +
       "gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE2D, " + texName + ")");
     var img = new Image();
     img.src = gl.canvas.toDataURL();
     document.body.appendChild(img);
  };
  
  function render() { 
      gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
      
      Object.keys(programs).forEach(function(p, pndx) {
          gl.useProgram(programs[p]);
          
          [
              { src: "SRC_ALPHA", dst: "ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA" },
              { src: "ONE", dst: "ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA" },
          ].forEach(function(b, bndx) {
               gl.blendFunc(gl[b.src], gl[b.dst]);
           
               Object.keys(textures).forEach(function(texName, tndx) {
                  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, textures[texName]);
                  gl.clearColor(0x3D/0xFF, 0x87/0xFF, 0xEA/0xFF, 1);
                  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
                  grabImage(p, b, texName);
              });
          });
      });
   }
}

main();
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
img {
    background-color: #3D87EA;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 256px;
    height: 256px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/3.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texcoord;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;
    
void main() {
   gl_Position = a_position;
   v_texcoord = a_texcoord;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shaders -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
    
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
</script>
<script id="pre-2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
    
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
void main() {
    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(textureColor.rgb * textureColor.a, textureColor.a);
}
</script>
<canvas id="c" width="32" height="32"></canvas>
<script type="not-js" id="i">data:image/png;base64,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</script>
```

There's a few solutions

1. Make sure transparent area actually has color in.

   In other words, if all the pixels in the top left of the image above are **RED** with 0 alpha then when the pixels get filtered they'll be blending (1,0,0,0) transparent red instead of (0,0,0,0) transparent black. Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this in most drawing programs.

   There's [a plugin for Photoshop that lets you do it called SuperPNG](http://www.fnordware.com/superpng/)  It lets you create a 4th channel for the alpha instead of using photoshop's transparency. That lets you set the alpha separate from the image.

   In your case you'd end up with an image with layers like this

   [image]

   Now there are no bad colors to blend with.
2. Switch to pre-multiplied alpha

   In this case before calling `gl.texImage2D` to upload the image call

   ```
   gl.pixelStorei(UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
   ```

   before calling `gl.texImage2D`. That tells WebGL to multiply the colors by their alpha when the image is loaded. You then use blending with

   ```
   gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
   ```
3. Turn off filtering in GL

   ```
   gl.texParameter(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
   gl.texParameter(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
   ```

   Assuming your source image doesn't have any bad colors this means GL won't making new bad colors as it filters but of course it also means if you scale or rotate the image you'll get aliasing.
4. Create your own mips

   Most apps use `gl.genereateMipmap` to generate mips but you can generate them yourself offline and upload them yourself. That's not a perfect solution either but it does let you use `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);

Combinations of the above

Comment: This fixed the black border problem, but how can I still be able to set the texture alpha (such as in a fade animation)?